# Spark Apache is not deleting "NULL" values

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a spark script that is supposed to delete null values in a dataframe build base on data read from a csv file.

This how my csv file look like:

```
Name,Surname,Age,Class,Categ
John,Snow,30,2nd,NULL
Alfred,Nobel,69,10th,m
Isaac,Newton,55,9th,m
```

So, I need to delete each row including a "NULL" value. To reach this result, This the code I am wrinting:

```
rdd = sc.textFile(dataset)
header = rdd.first()
data = rdd.filter(lambda x: x!=header).map(lambda line: line.replace("NULL","").split(","))
columns = header.split(",")
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
cleanedData = df.na.drop()
cleanedData.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).option("delimiter", ",").csv('cleanedData')
```

When I execute my code, it supposed to return a csv file with the following content: (remove the first row)

```
Name,Surname,Age,Class,Categ
Alfred,Nobel,69,10th,m
Isaac,Newton,55,9th,m
```

but what I am getting is (just replace the NULL value with an empty string but not deleting the row):

```
Name,Surname,Age,Class,Categ
John,Snow,30,2nd,
Alfred,Nobel,69,10th,m
Isaac,Newton,55,9th,m
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I execute my code, it supposed to ... (remove the first row)

It shouldn't. Empty string is not the same as `NULL`. In general you should avoid brittle manual parsing and use `csv` reader specifying `nullValue`:

```
spark.read.option("nullValue", "NULL").option("header", "true").csv(dataset)
```

but if you want to stick to your approach you should use `None`

```
lambda line: tuple(x if x != "NULL" else None for x in line.split(","))
```